# Displaying non repeating elements of array in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an array with different words in it which I want to be displayed randomly when the user taps a button.

```
var words = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4"] //etc...
//user taps button
currentWord.text = words.randomElement()
```

I've tried creating a variable with a random number, and then using words.remove(words[randomNumber], but when I run through the app it gives me the out of range error after a few clicks.

Are there any ways to avoid this?

Comment: Did you check [these similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+random+without+repetition)?

Comment: my bad. was able to figure it out now, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Out of range means you are trying to edit a item in your array that isn't there.

for example:

```
var words = ["word1", "word2"]
```

If you were to count that array it would return `1` becuase the count will start at 0. 
Now if you were to try the following:

```
words.remove(words[randomNumber])
```

the vaule of `randomNumber` must be either 0 or 1 otherwise you will receive index out of range

Answer (score 0):

Why not just completely forget about creating a random number and shuffle your array using the `shuffle()` method and call the first element of your array? The `shuffle()` method is O(n) complexity and you won't have to worry about your array going out of bounds.

```
var words = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4"]
let randomizedWordArray = words.shuffle()
currentWord.text = randomizedWordArray[0]
```

And if you truly don't want to worry about your array going out of bounds an even easier and more straight forward way to solve this problem is just calling the `randomElement()` method on the array.

```
currentWord.text = words.randomElement()
```

Comment: Agreed. Much better way to do it

Comment: Or even easier, why not just call the randomElement() method on the array. I'll add that solution to my answer above